# Maven - include external jars in final jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have been wondering how to include specific jar's into the final maven builded jar. I tried using **scope system** but it does not include it in jar.

Thank You

Comment: see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729442/maven-resources-plugin-flat-copy-of-resources

Answer (score 0):

One jar does not contain another. Web Archives (war) files contain jars, as do Enterprise Archives (ear) files.

Comment: Indeed. Probably the OP is referring to creating a 'fat jar'.

Comment: I want classes from those external jars to be used used when I deploy and run my application. I hope You know what I mean?

Comment: The Lutz Horn's comment is correct -- you need Shade.